# PySpark Read Parquet File Error - Illegal Parquet type: INT64 (TIMESTAMP(NANOS,true))

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I read parquet files using the pyspark function `sqlContext.read.parquet`. The files contain timestamp columns. Due to the fact that pyspark has its issues with writing nanosecond timestamps, I use pandas to write the data. The output format for the pandas timestamp columns with nanoseconds look like this: `2022-05-23 08:08:35.106226000`

With version 3.1.x I was to able read the data without any problems and spark automatically converts the timestamps into a long type, but under 3.2.x the following error occurs: `Illegal Parquet type: INT64 (TIMESTAMP(NANOS,true))`.

I would like to prevent reading all of my data with a manually defined schema since it would be a huge effort for me.

Is there a read option or another solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you may wanna check the `spark.sql.parquet.datetimeRebaseMode****` options (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html). Although its a bit concerning because those were introduced in Spark 3.0.

Comment: @mazaneicha unfortunately, this read option does not solve the problem